# deconstructing and reconstructing python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which I need to deconstruct its keys and values in perhaps two lists(or any other type that does the job) and later in another function, construct the exact same dictionary putting back the keys and values. What's the right way of approaching this?

Comment: I tried separating the keys and values in two lists using `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()`, now I have the lists but I'm not sure how I can create the same dictionary with those two lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict.items()` to get all the key-value pairs from the dictionary, then either store them directly...

```
>>> d = {"foo": 42, "bar": 23}
>>> items = list(d.items())
>>> dict(items)
{'bar': 23, 'foo': 42}
```

... or distribute them to two separate lists, using `zip`:

```
>>> keys, values = zip(*d.items())
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'bar': 23, 'foo': 42}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
k, v = d.keys(), d.values()

# Do stuff with keys and values
# -

# Create new dict from keys and values
nd = dict(zip(k, v))
```

Comment: Does `d.keys(), d.values()` guarantee that those are paired up correctly? Maybe better use `zip(*d.items())`... or just store the items in a list of tuples, without zipping at all.

Comment: I'm also curious if that guarantees they are paired correctly. tobias_k how do you use that `zip(*d.items())` in this context?

Comment: From the documentation it reads : "If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())."

Answer (score 0):

Better Don't deconstruct it. Where you need the keys and values as list you can get that with the following methods.

```
keyList=list(dict.keys())
valueList = [dict[key] for key in keyList] or [dict[key] for key in dict.keys()]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To deconstruct a Dict to two list

```
>>> test_dict={"a":1, "b":2}
>>> keyList=[]
>>> valueList =[]
>>> for key,val in test_dict.items():
...    keyList.append(key)
...    valueList.append(val)
>>> print valueList
[1, 2]
>>> print keyList
['a', 'b']
```

To construct from two list of key and value I would use zip method along with dict comprehension.

```
>>> {key:val for key,val in zip(keyList,valueList)}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```